# Nokogiri::XML::Builder turns out slower than Builder for generating XML in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

We have been using Rails' (2.3.3) Builder to generate XML Markup for our APIs for a while, when we thought that Nokogiri's Builder would generate XML faster (as many have pointed out).

The problem is, my benchmarks showed Nokogiri::Builder slower than regular Builder:

```
Nokogiri::Builder: 3.1314s
Builder:           2.1592s
```

for rendering exactly the same request 10 times. I've repeated similar tests in different environments multiple times so I am sure that Nokogiri is running slower.

Our application has lots of .xml.builder views that use many .xml.builder partials:

```
xml.instruct!
xml.feed do
  xml.stuff do
    xml.more_stuff(...)
  end
  xml.location do
    xml << render(:partial => shared/location, :object => mylocation)
  end
end
```

The above utilizes the shared/_location.xml.builder. Our application heavily uses such XML partials to organize code.

I changed to Nokogiri following "[Speed Up Your Rails XML Responses](http://matt.aimonetti.net/posts/2010/02/22/speed-up-your-rails-xml-responses/)" (see benchmark app there).

My Template handler looks like this:

```
class NokogiriBuilder < ActionView::TemplateHandler
  include ActionView::TemplateHandlers::Compilable

  def compile template
    "_set_controller_content_type(Mime::XML);" +
      "xml = ::Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(:encoding => 'UTF-8') { |xml| " +
      template.source +
      '}.to_xml; self.output_buffer = xml;'
  end 
end
```

When I tried to run my code through rubyprof, results show that create_element takes up a long amount of time!

```
 %self     total     self     wait    child    calls  name
 23.47      1.15     1.15     0.00     0.00      731  Mysql#query
  9.59      0.78     0.47     0.00     0.31     1437  Nokogiri::XML::Document#create_element
  7.96      3.61     0.39     0.00     3.61      867  <Module::Benchmark>#realtime
  5.51      0.27     0.27     0.00     0.00     1167  Nokogiri::XML::Node#encode_special_chars
  5.51      0.28     0.27     0.00     0.01     1370  Module#define_method
  5.10      0.26     0.25     0.00     0.01      346  Array#select
  3.88      0.19     0.19     0.00     0.00     5236  Module#constants
  3.27      0.90     0.16     0.00     0.83     1820  Array#collect
  2.45      0.13     0.12     0.00     0.01     1712  Rack::Lint::Assertion#assert
  2.24      1.09     0.11     0.00     1.09      554  ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::String::Inflections#constantize
  2.04      0.10     0.10     0.00     0.00       23  Nokogiri::XML::ParseOptions#initialize
  2.04      0.10     0.10     0.00     0.00      726  <Class::ActiveSupport::Callbacks::CallbackChain>#extract_options
```

I'm really wondering what's so special in my case that Nokogiri would turn out slower, though it has proved to be many times faster for many people!

No Tender Lovemaking? :-(

Comment: +1 for detailed information and profiling, but -1 for...what's the question? Why is one library slightly slower than another for your specific use case, when some blog entry made you think that it would always be faster in every case?

Comment: That's right, sort of, since [this](http://kete.lighthouseapp.com/projects/14288/tickets/177-tags-list-rss-feed-increasingly-slower), [this](http://railsontherun.com/2010/02/22/speed-up-your-rails-xml-responses/) and others have mentioned big improvements. As I am right now optimizing my app, this seemed an easy gain. The question is, specifically what could it be in my app to make an otherwise faster library slow? It could be something very wrong that I'm doing.

Comment: It's important to check the dates of blogs when counting on their information. The first was written two years before this question was posted, and in that time Rails would have had many upgrades, so it's easy to see why the results could be different. The internet never forgets, but information does go stale.

Comment: Agree with above comments.  There are perhaps a dozen factors that could affect performance unrelated to the XML parsing.  For example if you're using the version of Rails from 2009 are you also using and old version of ruby?  What OS?  Are you reading large files from a slow disk.  Nokogiri is likely faster at parsing once the XML is in memory, but getting it there and ready (even within Nokogiri) can vary tremendously.  Also, the size and complexity of what's being parsed matters -- for example, we're reading 100+ megabyte XML files and Nokogiri is faster in that case.